# how to hide div with java script?

Tags: javascript, hide

I have a vertical list which fixed in user viewport when user scroll it, in some  background is not good color, so I want to hide it when reach to that area. and when scroll to up get back.
I want to hide specific div or list when user reach to that div.

Comment: `.style = "display:none"` on div element "hides" the div via js

Comment: But seems you have multiple requirements. Here is why you should show your code. No one has access to your dev env

Comment: It sounds like you might find intersectionObserver useful - it will tell you when an element is in the viewport or when it goes out of it. Could you put some basic code which shows the sort of structure you have so we can help a bit more?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).